# Rails: Is there a way to associate a name with each locale?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization, locale, rails-i18n

I have 2 languages at the moment: English and Greek (:en & :el).

I'm using the globalize gem.

Is there a way so I can put them in a loop and then extract the name of each language?

For example is there something like the following:

```
I18n.locale.Name_of_the_locale
```

If yes, where do I declare/change it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution is to create a `:language_name` key inside your `en.yml` and `gr.yml`:

```
en:
  language_name: English

gr:
  language_name: Greek
```

Then simply call `I18n.t('language_name')`. If you need to have them all at once, you can still loop through all the available locales:

```
I18n.available_locales.map { |locale| I18n.t('language_name', locale: locale) }
```